# How to make My application in iTunes to be released manually after the approval?

Tags: iphone, app-store, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

I had an application which i want to upload to Appstore.

In earlier days there is an option for making my application available after approval any time i want manually.

Not automatically release after approval.But Now i am not getting that option during the application adding process,Can anybody help me in how we can achieve this now?

Comment: There is an option to release the application manually. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/32904060/3950397

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set specific release date in new iTunesConnect interface after approval?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32903878/how-to-set-specific-release-date-in-new-itunesconnect-interface-after-approval)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the availability date to whenever you want.