# How to set specific release date in new iTunesConnect interface after approval?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, autorelease

Can anyone tell me how to set a specific release date in new iTunesConnect interface, after approval with pending developer release state?

Our release should for some reason at a weekend now, so changing from manually release to a date would be nice. But now where the app is in pending developer release state, I can not find the option for a specific release date anymore.

Comment: i think you need to set before your application release. so now you have to release on particular date by manually. when you submit the app you have to set spcific release date. but i don't think now yo can set after approved app.

Comment: Hmm, that would be another strange Apple UI decision. Don't see a reason to strip this option after a review. It was possible in the past as far as I remember.

Answer (score 2):

According to Apple [App distribution guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/UsingiTunesConnect/UsingiTunesConnect.html):

> Use iTunes Connect to set a date when the app is available on the store. For example, you can choose a date that immediately releases the app to the store after it’s approved, or you can set a later date. Using a later availability date allows you to arrange other marketing activities around the launch of your app.

The screenshot in documentation is outdated though. See the image below.

[image]

Steps:

1. Login to iTunes connect
2. Select Apps
3. Select your application
4. Click Prepare for Submission
5. Scroll down the detail page to bottom to see option to manually
   release the app.

Note that if you set a date too early, it is entirely possible that your app will not be released until and unless the review is complete.

Also, if you decide to update your app during review time, you will have to restart entire process and lose progress on current app review.

Comment: Hi. With "After approval" I meant after the Apple Review, so I already submitted and said manually release at this point. Now I could directly put the app into the store, but the customer wants it released at a weekend so it would be nice to change it now to a specific date.

Comment: Since you selected manually already, there's nothing you can do now. You may start a new approval process with specified data but that would take another week.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I suggested, but I do not understand why Apple did that. Thx for your help.